# Enable NTLM support without SASL rebuild

Tags: 12.04, email, postfix, ms-exchange

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I want to use the Postfix as relay to a Microsoft Exchange server. I send a mail to my Postfix, it connects to the Exchange, authenticates and sends mail. I have an trouble with NTLM authorisation. When I sent mail I see this message into the Postfix log:

```
warning: mail.example.com [192.168.xxx.xxx]:25 offered no supported AUTH mechanisms: 'NTLM'
```

Into the  document [Postfix SASL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) is written to rebuild the SASL module with NTLM support option. But I don't want rebuild modules. I think the Ubuntu repository has packages with NTLM support enabled.

Postcong output:

```
$ postconf -a
cyrus
dovecot
```

Anybody know how to solve my trouble?

Comment: Can you add the output of `postconf -A` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick dive, and at first glace doesn't it look like cyrus is compiled with support for NTLM. Couldn't see the ntlm library in the ubuntu package, tho it is still possible it is built with NTLM and statically linked.

Yes, [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/191309-configure-cyrus-sasl-ntlm-plugin-postfix.html) is a solution but it do include to compile cyrus from source. But ofc. you will have to adopt it to fit the version of postfix\cyrus you are targeting.

Feel free to try to compile the support, and update your question with issues you are running into. Good Luck.